# My web page moves back and forth automatically while open magnifier with 200%

Tags: web, accessibility

I have a web page, when I click one button(by both using mouse click or using keyboard with tab and press), it will show some items, normally, it works perfect.

However, if I
1> open windows magnifier with 200%,
AND
2> use keyboard with tab and press
to trigger the button,

the items still shows correctly,
but the whole page moves back and forth in horizon automatically until I move mmouse or press any key.

++++++
I got the root cause:
As I input the follow code

```
document.addEventListener('focus',
     function()
     { console.log('focused: ', document.activeElement)
     },
     true);
```

in console to monitor the focused element,
it shows the focus are switch between two elements,
however, I try to set the two element with tabindex = 0 or -1,
and all the 4 combinations,
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a link to your website so that others can open it in their browsers and test it?

Comment: your are right, I should do that. But this is a company owned project, so I cannnot put it  
 public.

Comment: Can you put up an example of what you're trying to achieve, or post a reproducible code example? It's going to be very difficult to help you unless we can replicate the problem on our own machines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "docked", "full screen", or "lens" view for the magnifier?

[image]

I'm guessing "full screen" because in that mode, as you tab through a page, the magnifier will try to keep the keyboard focus within view.  You might have an issue where your focus is moving between two elements that both can't be displayed in the magnifier at the same time.  Usually it will just move the magnifier to the element that has focus.

I'd suggest trying "Docked" and "Lens" view first to see if you still have an issue.

Comment: You are right, but how to fix it? I cannot ask all user do that.